# Serialization of an abstract class with a list containing mixed subclassed object types

Tags: java, list, collections, abstract-data-type

I have an abstract class that defines the structure of a scoreitem to be drawn in a graphic. There  are multiple variants of the score items. They all have the same instance variables, but each has its own drawing implementation which is quite large and complex. These drawing implementations consist mainly of goniometric calculations and do hardly share any code.

In order to keep the code readable, I want to use a subclass for each variant. In the subclass I will define the drawing method implementation. See simplified example below.

```
abstract class ScoreItem {
  int score;
  Color color;
  ...
  
  abstract void draw();

  public class RadarItem extends ScoreItem {
    @Override
    public void draw() {
      // RADAR IMPLEMENTATION
      ...
    }
  }

  public class LineItem extends ScoreItem {
    @Override
    public void draw() {
      // LINE IMPLEMENTATION
      ...
    }
  }
etc.
}
```

Now, I want to use a Graphic class in which I have a list of ScoreItems. The list can contain different variants of the abstract ScoreItem, and the class must loop over the ScoreItems in order to draw them, like below:

```
public class Graphic {
  ...

  public void generate() {
    List<ScoreItem> scoreItems = ...;

    for (ScoreItem scoreItem : scoreItems) { scoreItem.draw(); }
  }
}
```

Now this should work; I tested it in a simple test project. However, where I'm running into problems; the Graphic class must be serialized and I'm getting into trouble with the deserialization. This doesn't work *(java.lang.RuntimeException: "class" field not found for abstract class)*. I assume GSON cannot deserialize into the abstract class. When I change the ScoreItem class into a regular class, obviously GSON deserialization works, but then I can't use the draw() method on the subclasses.

I hope I have described the problem adequately and consisely enough. Maybe it's just not good pracice to use a List with different object types. Any solutions or recommendations are greatly appreciated.

Comment: The point of an abstract class is: it cant be instantiated. Meaning: unless you have *something* in your JSON that would tell GSON which specific class you want ... you are broken. You know, when you want to have different kinds of apples in your basket, you somehow have to be able to tell the clerk which apple is of what kind.

Comment: And unrelated: when you want to inherit stuff, make it protected. And consider to NOT inherit raw fields. Instead, make those private, and have protected getters for example. Sharing fields is rarely a good design.

Comment: Are you *really* defining your concrete classes as inner classes of the abstract one (in addition to them inheriting from it)?  That appears completely unnecessary, and it makes any kind of serialization more complicated.

Comment: How is Gson supposed to know which subclass it is supposed to instantiate? Does the JSON object include an attribute that tells you what the class is supposed to be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the answers nudging me in the right direction, the solution was to use an GSON Interface Adapter (changed to an Abstract Adapter).

As described [here](https://technology.finra.org/code/serialize-deserialize-interfaces-in-java.html).